# Determine how to identify this runtime error message

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am receiving this error

> Error on bar 10000: Bar index value of 'x1' argument (0.00) in 'line.new()' is too far from the current bar index. Try using 'time' instead

It only appears on some charts, so I was looking for a way to identify this error so I can use the runtime error message with an if statement.

I'm looking to do something like

```
if thaterror
    runtime.error('my message')
```

I just don't know what that error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that you are passing 0 to `x1` argument of the `line.new()`. I believe this is not what you want to have and you simply have something wrong in your code.

As for the solution, you cannot go back more than 10000 bars to draw your line. So, you can check if your `x1` parameter is more than 10000 bars away from the current bar before you call `line.new()`.

```
_x1 = 5000    // Will throw the runtime error
//_x1 = 5001  // Will draw the line

if (bar_index == 15000)
    if (bar_index - _x1 < 10000)
        line.new(_x1, close, bar_index, close, extend=extend.both)
    else
        runtime.error("Your Message")
```